# Changing "From" but not "MAIL FROM" in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have an e-mail account, let's say `me@server.com`, which allows me to write and receive e-mails. I have also an alias, let's say `me@alias.com`, that redirects the e-mails written to this address to `me@server.com`. What I want is to send e-mails from Thunderbird using the server of `me@server.com` but with sender address `me@alias.com`.

I tried to use the [identity feature](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-identities) of Thunderbird. The problem is that it seems that Thunderbird uses the e-mail of the identity to fill in the "MAIL FROM" field of the smtp protocol, and that does not please the `server.com` server. I get an error "553 5.7.1 invalid sender". I would like to customize the "From" field of the mail content (with `me@alias.com`), but leave untouched the "MAIL FROM" one (i.e. uses `me@server.com` for this field).

To be clear, I do not really care about fully masking the address `me@server.com`. It would not be a problem if that address appeared in the metadata of the e-mail. I just want that at first glance the e-mail seems to have been sent from `me@alias.com`.